# Git, lost my changes

Tags: git

this prolebme is mainly because of bad wifi connection in the cafe I am in.
I did a number of changes on my local repo, eveyr time I did one I would push properly.
The latest one I did the Internet connection was on and off, so It did push and git log would show the commit , but git status showed a discrepancy between my local and remote.

Since my last push was a success, I thought I would do this

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

But crap, this got rid of all commit I did today and head is now some commit I did yesterday, and when I go to bitbucket to see the repo it doesn;t even show today's changes.

Someone please tell me I didn't just screw myself over? is there a solution for this?

Comment: Let's be clear: git didn't lose your changes; YOU lost your changes. ;)

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: No need to be didactic:-) The same thing just happened to me today. I was using smartgit though, all of sudden my local commit disappeared after I pulled from the remote repository. It never happened before. Luckily, I found this thread and I managed to get the commit back and do the merge with the remote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the `git reflog` to see commit hashes for all your recent activity.

Git won't garbage collect unreachable commits for at least 2 weeks (unless you explicitely tell it to)

Alternatively, `git log -g` might help you:

> `-g, --walk-reflogs`
>
> Instead of walking the commit ancestry chain, walk reflog entries from
>   the most recent one to older ones.

Comment: yes I just did a git reflog, and whew the commit is there, now just so I don;t screw myself again, what did I do wrong? and what command should I run once I have the commit hash I need.

Comment: You can `git reset --hard` to any commit, not just named branches. You could also `merge` that "lost" commit hash

Comment: As to what you did wrong, I would guess that "my last push was a success" probably wasn't actually true and you missed an error message somewhere. Unfortunately it's impossible to tell without seeing a lot more of your actual terminal session

Comment: I am trying, but even for that this cafe's wifi is crap, ahh just got it, thnx.